# File compression formats and container file formats

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, avro, parquet

It is generally said that any compression format like Gzip, when used along with a container file format like avro and sequence (file formats), will make the compression format splittable.

Does this mean that the blocks in the container format get compressed based on the preferred compression (like gzip) or something else.  Can someone please explain this? Thanks!

Well, I think the question requires an update.

Update:

Do we have a straightforward approach to convert a large file in a non-splittable file compression format (like Gzip) into a  splittable file (using a container file format such as Avro, Sequence or Parquet) to be processed by MapReduce?

Note: I do not mean to ask for workarounds such as uncompressing the file, and again compressing the data using a splittable compression format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sequence files if you specify `BLOCK` compression, each block will be compressed using the specified compression codec. Blocks allow Hadoop to split data at the block level, while using compression (where the compression itself isn't splitable) and skip whole blocks without needing to decompress them.

Most of this is described on the Hadoop wiki: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SequenceFile

> Block compressed key/value records - both keys and values are
>   collected in 'blocks' separately and compressed. The size of the
>   'block' is configurable.

For Avro this is all very similar as well: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Object+Container+Files

> Objects are stored in blocks that may be compressed. Syncronization
>   markers are used between blocks to permit efficient splitting of files
>   for MapReduce processing.
>
> Thus, each block's binary data can be efficiently extracted or skipped
>   without deserializing the contents.

The easiest (and usually fastest) way to convert data from one format into another is to let MapReduce do the work for you. In the example of:

`GZip Text -> SequenceFile`

You would have a map only job that uses the `TextInputFormat` for input and outputs `SequenceFileFormat`. This way you get a 1-to-1 conversion on the number of files (add a reduce step if this needs changing) and you do the conversion in parallel if there are lots of files to convert.

Comment: Can a container format be applied on top of a file which was compressed using a non-splitable compression format?

Comment: The term `container` is a bit confusing, they are `file formats`, so there must be some form of conversion if you want to take an existing file and convert it into another format. You can't just _wrap_ the file in something.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By mentioning "container file formats", I meant only the hadoop file formats such as Avro.

Comment: Just noticed you updated the question, so i added a little bit more to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know what you are really talking about... but any file can be splitted at any point.

Why i say this... hoping you are using something like Linux or similar.

On Linux it is (not too much) easy to create a block device that is really stored on the concatenation of some files.

I mean:

- You split a file in as many chunks as you want, each of a different size, no need to be ood or even size, multiple of 512 bytes, etc., whatever size you want, mathematicaly expresed splitted_file_size=(desired_size mod 1).
- You define a block device that concatenates all files in the correct order
- You define a symbolic link to such device

That way you can have a BIG file (more than 16GiB, more than 4GiB) stored on one FAT32 partition (that has a limit of 4GiB-1 bytes per file)... and access it on-the-fly and transparently... thinking only on read.

For read/write... there is a trick (that is the complex part) that works:

- Split the file (this time in chunks of N*512 bytes)
- Define a device driver parametrized (so it knows how to allocate more chunks by creating more files)

On Linux i had used on the past some tools (command line) that do all the job, and they let you create a virtual container resizable on the fly, that will use files of an exact size (including the last one) and exposes it as a regular block device (where you can do a dd if=... of=... to fill it) and a virtual file associated with it.

That way you have:

- Some not so big files of identical size
- They will hold inside the real data of the stream
- They are created / deleted as needed (grow / shrink or truncate)
- They are exposed as a regular file on some point
- Accesing such file will be as seen the concatenation

Maybe that gives you idea on other aproach to the problem you are having:

- Instead of tweak the compression system, just put a layer (a little bit more complex that a simple loop device) that do on the fly and transparently the split/join

Such tools exist, i do not remember the name, sorry! But i remember the one for read only (dvd_double_layer.* are on a FAT32):

```
# cd /mnt/FAT32
# ls -lh dvd_double_layer.*
total #
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 3.5G 2017-04-20 13:10 dvd_double_layer.000
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 3.5G 2017-04-20 13:11 dvd_double_layer.001
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0.2G 2017-04-20 13:12 dvd_double_layer.002
# affuse dvd_double_layer.000 /mnt/transparent_concatenated_on_the_fly
# cd /mnt/transparent_concatenated_on_the_fly
# ln -s dvd_double_layer.000.raw dvd_double_layer.iso
# ls -lh dvd_double_layer.*
total #
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 7.2G 2017-04-20 13:13 dvd_double_layer.000.raw
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 7.2G 2017-04-20 13:14 dvd_double_layer.iso
```

Hope this idea can help you.